# SFDX Exports Ballooning in Size

Tags: salesforcedx, object, salesforcedx-cli

I've got a scheduled job that pulls down a complete snapshot of some objects' data from Salesforce using the sfdx CLI.  I store this data on S3; it's useful for backup purposes and some analysis.

A query looks something like this:

> sfdx force:data:soql:query "SELECT Id, Name, (other fields here) FROM Account" --resultformat=csv > today's_date.csv

In the past few days, the job started failing.  I've tried to run the queries manually from my command line, and noticed that the size of the exports has increased by 100x - a complete snapshot of my Accounts in csv used to be ~2MB, and now it's > 400MB.  I've confirmed with our Salesforce admin that we haven't added new columns.  Even if I just pull down the ID column, I end up with a csv that's ~50MB.

What might be causing this?

Comment: You mention columns not changing but what about the number of rows growing?

Comment: Good question @KeithC; the number of rows hasn't changed meaningfully (<3%)

Comment: So what's in the 400MB CSV, if your data hasn't materially changed?